# Will wingtip drag always be more for a smaller aircraft, keeping constant aspect ratio?

Tags: drag, wing-tip-vortex

Sometime ago, I came across an article (I couldn't find it) which stated that wingtip drag was only related to absolute wingspan. That is, for the same wingspan and lift force, varying the chord will not change the wingtip drag. I have also seen an answer on Aviation SE where this appears to be mathematically proven. 
So my question is; am I correct in stating that , for a given lift force, wingtip drag only depends on wingspan, not chord, and thus that smaller aircraft are doomed to have more wingtip drag than larger ones?

Comment: While that article used imprecise terminology, it was correct.Would the answers to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/716/what-dictates-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-aircrafts-wing/8797#8797) help to answer yours? Or [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36062/what-is-the-formula-for-induced-drag/36064#36064)? Or [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/how-can-larger-wingspan-decrease-the-strength-of-wingtip-vortices/67518#67518)?

Comment: Yes, these links helped very much. This question is answered. Thank you very much.